# Android stock mail app does not retrieve IMAP mails

Tags: email, imap, samsung-galaxy-note-2, stock-email-app

Last week my native Android mail client stopped retrieving mail.  It can still send mail.  An identically configured K-9 mail app does retrieve email.  The server is a dovecot mail server, both clients use the IMAP protocol.

When the Android native client connects, it sends:

```
239 SELECT "INBOX"
240 UID SEARCH 44:68 NOT DELETED
241 NOOP
242 NOOP
243 CAPABILITY
244 LIST "" "INBOX.*"
```

The server's reply to the UID SEARCH:

```
* SEARCH 11201 11202 11203 11204 11205 11206 11207 11208 11209 11210 11211 11212 11213 11214 11215 11216 11217 11218 11219 11220 11221 11222 11223 11224 11225
240 OK Search completed (0.000 secs).
```

These results look exactly like the results the K-9 app gets.  Any idea why the native client does not pickup the mail?  It doesn't show any mail at all.

Comment: Have you tried removing the account in the stock email app and readding it?

Comment: @ZnewmaN: Yes. Before I removed it it still showed last weeks mail, after that the inbox was entirely empty.